# Insert xml data into sql tables

Tags: sql, xml, import

I have an xml document with the following format:

```
<response username="123" customerName="CustomerName" siteName="SiteName" customerID="123" Period="2009">
  <topics>
    <topic name="MyTopic">
      <department name="MyDepartment" parent="OriginalDepartment">
        <questionHead result="Go" group="Group A" surveyID="1" questionID="2" responseID="3">
          <question>My Question</question>
          <answer>My Ansert</answer>
          <comment>Good Answer</comment>
          <reference>Page 10</reference>
        </questionHead>
        <questionHead result="Go" group="Group A" surveyID="1" questionID="2" responseID="3">
          <question>My Question</question>
          <answer>My Ansert</answer>
          <comment>Good Answer</comment>
          <reference>Page 10</reference>
        </questionHead>
```

...

There are multiple, topics and departments.  I need to insert this data into a sql server table.  My table has this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions](
    [ImportQuestionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TopicName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [DepartmentName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ParentDepartmentName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SurveyID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ResponseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PageNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Result] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [GroupName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [QuestionText] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [AnswerText] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Comment] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Reference] [varchar](500) NULL)
```

So I've imported my xml file into a temporary table with a xml column and now I'm trying to parse the file and put it into a relational table.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
INSERT INTO [SRCL_XmlTest].[dbo].[Questions]
           field list...
SELECT tab.col.value('./topic/@name', 'varchar(100)') as TopicName,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/@name', 'varchar(100)') as DepartmentName,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/@parent', 'varchar(100)') as ParentDepartmentName,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/questionH/@questionID', 'int') as QuestionID,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/questionH/@surveyID', 'int') as SurveyID,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/questionH/@responseID', 'int') as ResponseID,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/questionH/@pageNumber', 'int') as PageNumber,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/questionH/@orderNumber', 'int') as OrderNumber,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/questionH/@result', 'varchar(10)') as ResultColourCode,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/questionH/@group', 'varchar(100)') as GroupName,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/questionH/question', 'varchar(500)') as QuestionText,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/questionH/answer', 'varchar(500)') as AnswerText,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/questionH/comment', 'varchar(500)') as Comment,
        tab.col.value('./topic/department/questionH/reference', 'varchar(500)') as Reference
FROM FileImport
CROSS APPLY
XmlData.nodes('//response/topics') AS tab(col)
```

However, I keep getting the error: XQuery [FileImport.XmlData.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

This is because there are multiple topic nodes in the xml?  I've tried changing my select to:
XmlData.nodes('//response/topics/topic/department/questionHead/question') AS tab(col)

and I can now access the question, but can't get anywhere near the answer.  Any one with some ideas?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302064/sql-server-2005-xml-query-works-value-requires-singleton-found-xdtuntype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a singleton in every xml.value:

```
tab.col.value('(./topic)[1]/@name', 'varchar(100)')
tab.col.value('(./topic/department)[1]/@name', 'varchar(100)')
...
```

Whitouth an XML schema declaration there is no way SQL can guess that topics/topic is a singleton, so you have to explicitly force it with the `(...)[1]`.

**Update**

If your XML has multiple <topic> elements for a <topics> parent your query is incorrect. You need to move the `topic` into the `nodes`:

```
SELECT
tab.col.value('@name',...)
tab.col.value('(./department)[1]',...)
...
FROM ...
CROSS APPLY ... nodes('//response/topics/topic') as tab(col);
```

This way you project a row for each topic in a all topics nodes. Your original query can only select one single topic from each topics parent.

Comment: Probably should be: `CROSS APPLY ... nodes('/response/topics/topic') as tab(col);`, no? I doubt the `/topics/topic` XPath expression would select anything useful.....

Comment: @marc: In my edit I didn't have the original query so I just typed the from memory. I'll edit to avoid confusion.

Comment: Wasn't exact solution but you put me on the right path. My xpath needed to be: 
<code>XmlData.nodes('//response/topics/topic/department/questionHead') AS tab(col)</code>. 

Also then my select list needed to be similar to (rest left for brevity): 

<code> SELECT tab.col.value('../../@name', 'varchar(100)') as TopicName, 
tab.col.value('../@name', 'varchar(100)') as DepartmentName, tab.col.value('@questionID', 'int') as QuestionID, tab.col.value('./question[1]', 'varchar(500)') as QuestionText </code> 

So essentially I needed to go to the most child node and work my way back

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[1]` inside the xpath of your `.value()` For instance:

```
tab.col.value('./topic[1]/@name', 'varchar(100)')
```

instead of just

```
tab.col.value('./topic/@name', 'varchar(100)')
```