# How to get SQL Server XQUERY to return something other than "There is no element named [Element]"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xquery

Apologies if this is answered elsewhere. I keep getting the error message
XQuery [Mytable.XMLData.nodes()]: There is no element named 'Answer'

```
SELECT 
ref.value('/','nvarchar(1000)')
FROM   Mytable CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('Answer') R(ref)
```

-

```
--XML of Row
<Answer xmlns="http://TempNameSpace.com/AnswerData.xsd" Type="Deliverable">
  <Deliverable>
    <Title>test</Title>
    <Description>test</Description>
    <DueDate>2010-02-16T08:59:59</DueDate>
  </Deliverable>
</Answer>
```

I've tried several different variations on getting the root node ('answer'), or any of the child nodes
if, however i change my statement to read

```
SELECT 
ref.value('/','nvarchar(1000)')
FROM   Mytable CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/') R(ref)
```

i get the result
testtest2010-02-16T08:59:59

I'd ultimately like this data in tabular format, something like

```
SELECT 
    ref.value('/Title','nvarchar(1000)') as Title
    ref.value('/Description','nvarchar(1000)') as Description

etc..
    FROM   Mytable CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/Deliverable') R(ref)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302064/sql-server-2005-xml-query-works-value-requires-singleton-found-xdtuntype

Comment: yes that does help a bit. Seems when i remove the namespace declaration on the root node, i can now find my elements. However, none of my elements have explicit namespace prefixes(eg, <ns1:Answer>blah</ns1:Answer> )

Should it? i suppose i can just remove this xmlns="http://TempNameSpace.com/AnswerData.xsd" line from my xml, however i was planning on using that to validate the xml

Thanks

Comment: OOPS!!! 
@Myself: Instead, pay attention to the (/)[1] part.

that helps

Comment: hmm.. only works with no namespace declaration.... sad.

Comment: Is there a better way of not having to declare the namespace in each reference?

Comment: @Beta033: yes!! See my answer - use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES(.....)` around your statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not paying attention to the XML namespace in play:

```
<Answer xmlns="http://TempNameSpace.com/AnswerData.xsd" Type="Deliverable" 
        **********************************************
```

You need to take that into account when querying - do something like this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://TempNameSpace.com/AnswerData.xsd' AS ns)
SELECT 
  ref.value('(ns:*)[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)')
FROM Mytable 
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/ns:Answer') R(ref)
```

You need to reference everything inside `<Answer>` with the `ns:` XML namespace prefix.