# SQL xpath for level 1 node values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xpath

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in sql 2008 to select the id values from some xml like this.

```
DECLARE @idPolygonXML XML

SET @idPolygonXML = 
'<polygons>
    <id>35</id>
    <id>36</id>
    <id>37</id>
    <id>38</id>
    <id>39</id>
    <id>40</id>
</polygons>'
```

I can get the id for a specific index but I need all of them and I keep getting 'value() requires a singleton'.

Does anyone know how I can get all these values without changing the xml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[SQL Server 2005\]: XML query() works, value() requires singleton found xdt:untypedAtomic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302064/sql-server-2005-xml-query-works-value-requires-singleton-found-xdtuntyp)

Comment: Are you trying to get them all as individual rows?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx

This isn't tested, but your query would look something like this

```
SELECT T2.ID.query('.')
CROSS APPLY @idPolygonXML.nodes('/polygons/id') as T2(ID)
```

Comment: That still brings back the nodes though as in <id>35</id> instead of just 35. I can do this but it's not nice: SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(T2.ID.query('.') as nvarchar(30)), '<id>', ''), '</id>', '') as int)
FROM @idPolygonXML.nodes('/polygons/id') as T2(ID)

Comment: try `T2.ID.query('value(.)')`

Comment: Or even simpler: use `SELECT T2.ID.value('(.)[1]', 'int')` and be done with it ...